# Lighting Chanuka candles on Erev Shabbat

Tags: chanuka, candle-lighting, shabbat, health-safety-shmira

Since it's not common sense to leave a fire unattended (or against an apartment building's guidelines to have unattended fires), what's the general minhag for lighting Chanuka candles on Erev Shabbat when going to Shul for Minyan and no one is home to watch the candles burn?  Is there any Halachik sources for doing a particular minhag?

Comment: Benjamin Pick, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the important question! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking "register," above.

Answer (score 2):

If this would prevent one from performing the Mitzvah Dirabanan (positive Rabbinic Commandment) of lighting Hanukah lights, then one should stay home from Shul and pray alone. Praying with a Minyan (with at least 9 other Jewish men) is only obligatory when possible.